# Dll exporting a class with a variadic template

Tags: c++, class

I have been looking around for a while now but haven't found anything useful on my issue. I have a variadic template class for managing events. The class is fully contained in it's own header. Now the issue with this class is that it is used in a library that is dynamically linked.

Here is the relevant code:

```cpp
// Definitions.h
#ifdef _ARTEMIS_EXPORT // _ARTEMIS_EXPORT is defined when compiling the library.
#define ARTEMIS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ARTEMIS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // _ARTEMIS_EXPORT

#define MAX_INVOKE 64
```

```cpp
// Event.h

#pragma once
#include <memory.h>

#include "Definitions.h"

template<typename FN>
class ARTEMIS_API Event {};

template<typename... A>
class ARTEMIS_API Event<void(*)(A...)> {
public:
    typedef void(*LPFUNCTION)(A...);

private:
    LPFUNCTION lpszFunctions[MAX_INVOKE];

public:
    inline Event() { memset(lpszFunctions, 0x00, sizeof(lpszFunctions)); }

    inline void Invoke(A... params) const { // LNK2019
        for (INT i = 0; i < MAX_INVOKE; i++)
            if (lpszFunctions[i])
                lpszFunctions[i](params...);
    }

    inline void operator+=(_In_ LPFUNCTION lpFunction) { // LNK2019
        for (INT i = 0; i < MAX_INVOKE; i++) {
            if (!lpszFunctions[i]) {
                lpszFunctions[i] = lpFunction;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    inline void operator-=(_In_ LPFUNCTION lpFunction) { // LNK2019
        for (INT i = 0; i < MAX_INVOKE; i++) {
            if (lpszFunctions[i] == lpFunction) {
                lpszFunctions[i] = nullptr;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When using this library, it outputs linker warnings (but does compile and seems to work fine) whenever I do not declare the class as dllexport, but when I declare the class as dllexport and then try and dllimport it in a different project, the linker throws LNK2019 errors for the member methods and operators contained in the class. My question is if there is any way to dllexport the class without these linker errors occuring? For context, the rest of this library compiles and links just fine, it is this one class that is causing me trouble.

Comment: At the risk of oversimplifying, your template isn't going to get compiled into the DLL, so you shouldn't mark it as dllexport. Templates need to be resolved at compile time, not runtime. This part of your library is header-only.

Comment: Oh, and using `inline` on functions that defined inside the class definition is redundant--a member function defined inside the class definition is `inline` by default.

Comment: I think that if the compiler decide not to inline your functions, then it would not be exported but the compiler still think it can be imported when compiling the application/library that use that DLLs...

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes, I know templated classes are header-only. My question is moreso about the linker raising warnings when compiling and using my library, and if that is something that I should worry about or disregard. And for the inlining thing, I am aware, but I like to explicitly define my functions as inline.

Comment: It's the linker giving a warning, not the compiler. It's telling you that there are unresolved externals--since you're using a template, the member functions don't exist until the template is instantiated over some type. The code "works" because any code that uses it includes the header, so code the instantiates the template generates its own version of each member function it needs.